# Problema con herencia java

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo la clase artista con los siguientes atributos y sus correspondientes getters y setters:

```
public class Artista {
public String Dni;
public String Nombre;
public int AñoNacimiento;
public String Sexo;
```

El problema me viene al intentar heredarla desde otra clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Dónde está mi fallo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en tu clase Artista debes tener un Constructor que coincida con la cantidad y tipos de parametros de la siguiente forma:

```
   public Artista(String Dni, String Nombre, int AñoNacimiento, String Sexo) {
        this.Dni = Dni;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.AñoNacimiento = AñoNacimiento;
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya creaste tu constructor? el Constructor Artista en la clase Artista no se puede aplicar a tipos dados; por lo cual no encuentra argumentos.

```
public Artista(String Dni, String Nombre, int AñoNacimiento, String Sexo) {
    this.Dni = Dni;
    this.Nombre = Nombre;
    this.AñoNacimiento = AñoNacimiento;
    this.Sexo = Sexo;
}
```